# Java helper function to round a number to the specified number of decimal places

Tags: java, floating-point, fixed-point

The function I need:

> Rounds a double to the specified number of decimal places

I figured this would be a part of `java.lang.math`, but inexplicably it doesn't have a `round` function that returns a `double`. Thus, my proposed solution is to add my own `round` function in a `MathEx` class.

```
/**
 * Holds generic math functions to extend the capabilities of the java.lang.Math class
 */
public class MathEx {

    /**
     * Rounds a double to the specified number of decimal places using the ubiquitous "half up" rounding method
     * @param numberToRound The number to be rounded
     * @param numberOfDecimals The number of decimals to include in the rounded number
     * @return The rounded number
     */
    public static double round(double numberToRound, int numberOfDecimals) {

        return new BigDecimal(numberToRound)
                    .setScale(numberOfDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
                    .doubleValue();
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate feedback on the overall strategy, the Javadoc comments, and the naming conventions.

Comment: The problem is interesting, but suggesting it to be solved through `BigDecimal`... I don't expect that to be a choice that the Java developers will agree with.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, interesting that you say that; [rofl was just suggesting](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86062/68938) that I "keep everything as a BigDecimal number"

Comment: If you need exact precision, then using a `BigDecimal` is pretty much the only option you have. If you don't need the exact precision, a version of Manny Meng's answer should suit you.

Answer (score 3):

This question makes assumptions which are not supported by the actual implementations of `double` in Java (or most other languages).

`double` is a floating-point number format, which has a number of odd behaviours that simply do not support 'rounding' in a consistently accurate way.

Consider the following code:

```
    double d = (v * 10 + 4) / 10_000_000.0;
    double rescale = round(d, 6) * 1_000_000_000.0;
```

That code takes an input value `v`, multiplies it by 10, adds 4, and then divides it by 10 million.

Consider an input value `65`. Take that, multiply by `10`, and add `4`, to get `654`. Now, divide `654` by `10` million, to get `0.0000654`.

Now, round that value to 6 decimals, and get: `0.0000650`, right?

Then multiply that by 1 billion to get `65000`

Unfortunately, the actual result is:

```
64999.999999999990000000
```

The reason is that `0.000065` does not exist. Sure, many things that print numbers in Java will print a rounded value for you, but any math you do will have small errors inconsistent with your expectations.

The bottom line?

**Rounding floating-point numbers to any fractional value will result in occasional errors.**

The solution is to keep everything as a `BigDecimal` number. Do not use your method unless you know what you are sacrificing.

[Here is an ideone](http://ideone.com/JlKsaB), it loops through small values until it finds one which causes errors. The first error it finds is at 65 millionths.

Comment: That's interesting. This is for an application with 100k+ lines of code, so I can't *change* what's there. However, would you suggest that my future Java code should "only use primitive doubles when performance is a concern"? Class members, function arguments... all BigDecimal? Or would you agree with the sentiment in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3413493/4471300) and [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) which is "only use BigDecimal (or C#'s 'decimal') when you need an exact representation"?

Comment: The standard Java response is this article: [What every programmer should know about floats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If procision is important, then use BigDecimals, or know your error sources.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new `BigDecimal` object is a bit expensive. Why don't you do:

```
public static double round(double numberToRound, int numberOfDecimals) {
    int tenPow = Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals);
    return Math.round(numberToRound * tenPow) / tenPow;
}
```

This method is self explanatory:

1. It first gets \$10^n\$ where \$n\$ is the number of decimals
2. Then multiplies the number to round with the previous result, and rounds it to the nearest integer
3. Finally divide \$10^n\$ from the result

This way, you don't have to create a `BigDecimal`.

You can further increase efficiency by making your own `pow()` method that only accepts a `double` and an `int`:

```
public static double pow(double x, int toPow) {
    if (toPow == 1) {
        return x;
    } else if (toPow == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (toPow < 0) {
        return pow(x, toPow + 1) / x;
    } else {
        return pow(x, toPow - 1) * x;
    }
}
```

Since `Math.pow()` also has to deal with stuff like \$2^{1.5}\$ and has to use a more complex algorithm to figure out the result, so a simple recursive algorithm can easily be more efficient than `Math.pow()`.

Comment: How confident are you that this is better in any way? You assume that creating a `BigDecimal` is necessarily more expensive than what you are doing here. IMO, this code needs to be much more efficient before it's worth sacrificing the readability of the OP's original code.

Comment: @Duncan Not really far fetched that it is, without even looking at either code base. BigDecimal is an object, where Manny's answer deals with primitives.